# css animation on "content:" doesn't work on Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, animation, css-selectors, css-animations

I have an animation set on `:before` that works fine on Chrome but it doesn't work on Safari (IOS9 iPhone or 9 - El Capitan) neither on Firefox.

```css
.hey {
  color: white;
}
.hey:before {
  content: 'Hey \a there';
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
 -moz-animation: heyThere 2250ms steps(11); /* for firefox */
  -webkit-animation: heyThere 2250ms steps(11); /* for safari, chrome & opera */
}

@keyframes heyThere {
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
@-moz-keyframes heyThere { /* animation for firefox */
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
@-webkit-keyframes heyThere { /* animation for chrome, safari & opera */
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
```

```html
<div class="hey">Hey there</div>
```

Comment: One glaring issue I see is that you don't have an unprefixed `animation` property. You should always have one of those. Also note that Firefox hasn't needed prefixes for `animation` in 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@asimovwasright answer is right.

To avoid so much repetition on css, I used a `@for` with SCSS to loop through all available spans (in this case 8)

```
.hey {
    span {
        color: transparent;
        animation: heyThere 500ms ease-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;

        $chars: 8;
        @for $i from 1 through $chars {
            &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
                animation-delay: 1200+70ms*$i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<h2 class="hey">
   <span>H</span>
   <span>e</span>
   <span>y</span>
   <br>
   <span>t</span>
   <span>h</span>
   <span>e</span>
   <span>r</span>
   <span>e</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Ah ye, scss makes it much better!

Answer (score 4):

I also gone through the entire web I didn't found any thing, according to the following reference we can only achieve with JavaScript.

> In my own testing animating content has only worked in stable desktop
>   Chrome (v46 at time of writing). No support anywhere else. No Safari
>   on desktop or iOS. No Firefox. No IE. Each of these browsers will
>   ignore the animation, showing only the original content in the pseudo
>   element.

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/#article-header-id-2)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Pavan Kumar Jorrigala it is not possible to animate the `content` property of a pseudo element except in Chrome on desktop.

Here is an ass-backwards approach to what you are trying to achieve:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/jka75070/1/)

```css
.hey span {
  color: transparent;
  animation: heyThere 100ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hey span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 900ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1100ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1300ms;
}
.hey span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 1500ms;
}

@keyframes heyThere {
    0% {color: transparent;}
  100% {color: red;}
}
```

```html
<div class="hey">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>y&nbsp;</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>e</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yh I did remember this tweak last night falling asleep, it's a really smart approach x)

Comment: Ye, it's a bit crazy, and not very scalable, but it works! :-) Why not JS though? You could write a much more scalable function.

Comment: Because this is the beginning of the website (intro) and i don't want to use JS on loading. And CSS is much smoother/faster than JS. Also i want to support websites without JS. a personal project i'm working on ;)

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: Check my own answer to complete your solution ;)

Comment: here is it in practice ;) www.sandrina-p.net

Comment: ehehe you kinda helped with something, thank you! :D

Answer (score -1):

in safari and firefox the code isn't animation, instead you'll have to write -moz-animation and also -webkit-animation, like this code:

```
.hey {
  color: white;
}
.hey:before {
  content: 'Hey \a there';
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  animation: heyThere 2250ms steps(11);
  -moz-animation: heyThere 2250ms steps(11); /* for firefox */
  -webkit-animation: heyThere 2250ms steps(11); /* for safari, chrome & opera */
}

@keyframes heyThere {
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
@-moz-keyframes heyThere { /* animation for firefox */
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
@-webkit-keyframes heyThere { /* animation for chrome, safari & opera */
    0% {content: "";}
    1% {content: "";}
    75% {content: "";}
    77% {content: "H";}
    80% {content: "He";}
    83% {content: "Hey";}
    85% {content: "Hey ";}
    87% {content: "Hey \a t";}
    90% {content: "Hey \a th";}
    93% {content: "Hey \a the";}
    95% {content: "Hey \a ther";}
    97% {content: "Hey \a there";}
    100% {content: "Hey \a there";}
}
```

`

Comment: I did that and still doesn't work. other animations work well, this one, i think because of content:, doesn't work

Answer (score -3):

Try adding a display property to the :before. For example, add display:block; and see if that affects the animation.

Comment: Did you try this before you posted the answer? Please test solutions before submitting them; you'd have realized that your answer does not solve the OP's problem.