# Change part of a text using CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a text in an HTML page and I want to change a part of it with an animation.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236440/change-text-with-a-css3-animation) but it is not working in my case or it seems not that solution I was looking for.
Here is my code:

```css
.change:before {
  content: '2';
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: change-letter;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes change-letter {
  0% { opacity: 0.5; }
  17% { opacity: 0; content: "3"; }
  34% { opacity: 0.5; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  66% { opacity: 0.5; }
  85% { opacity: 0; content: "2"; }
  100% { opacity: 0.5; }
}
```

```html
<span>My application version <span class="change"></span></span>
```

As you can see the animation is not working as expected. I mean that "2" appears two time before "3" and then "2" appear again with opacity 1 instead of 0.5. Please have a look a the CSS code and the look at the animation carefully. It seems not to follow the CSS code for every step of the animation. Can you figure out what is wrong with my code? How to make the final part of the text changing in the right way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "not working as expected" - you forgot to mention what your expectations are, and how they differ from the results.

Comment: I did edit my question. Hope it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: `before { content: '2';` ==> `before { content: '4';`   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check it out

```css
.change:before {
  content: '2';
  font-size: 100%;
  animation-name: change-letter;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes change-letter {
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "2"
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    content: "2"
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "2"
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "3"
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    content: "3"
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "3"
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "3"
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "2"
  }
}
```

```html
<span>My application version <span class="change"></span></span>
```

Comment: It is still working bad... Can you see that "2" blinks two times before "3" appears?

Comment: what is your expectation can you please tell me just the requirement

Comment: "2" has opacity 1 -> opacity 0.5 -> opacity 0; then "3" appears with opacity 0.5 -> opacity 1 -> opacity 0.5 -> opacity 0; then "2" appears again with opacity 0.5 -> opacity 1 -> and so on...

Comment: I have update the code please check it out. @smartmouse

Comment: if this work for you please make it as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for. Thank you!