# CSS @-webkit-keyframes animation not working

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-animations, keyframe

### Problem

Having trouble getting CSS @-webkit-keyframe animations to work against a `<span>` element. The following code works great on Chrome, but Safari v.12.0.1 doesn't seem to understand what I want it to do - it doesn't animate through the pre-defined keyframes.

### Current Status

After doing a lot of research, I've noticed this seems to be a common problem, especially here on Stack Overflow. Problem is, everyone's issues seem to vary based on animation or transition need and I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. After trying to use the shorthand CSS animation property `{ -webkit-animation: change 6s infinite; }`) to no avail, I tried breaking out and listing each CSS animation property individually as I noticed that has worked for some, but it hasn't helped me either.

I cannot figure out what I'm missing here. I've even checked to see that I'm meeting the [Safari CSS Visual Effects Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingWithKeyframes/AnimatingWithKeyframes.html) and, as far as I can tell, I'm meeting all requirements for keyframe animations to a 'T'; I have a name, a duration, and I have keyframes. I'm truly at a loss here.

Appreciate any help anyone can provide!

```css
/* Setting display property to block */

span {
  display: block;
}


/* Setting span animation and keyframes */

span:before {
  display: block;
  content: "FIRST STRING";
  animation: change 6s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Safari and Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
    content: "FIRST STRING";
  }
  25% {
    content: "SECOND STRING";
  }
  50% {
    content: "THIRD STRING";
  }
  75% {
    content: "FOURTH STRING";
  }
  100% {
    content: "FIRST STRING";
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    content: "FIRST STRING";
  }
  25% {
    content: "SECOND STRING";
  }
  50% {
    content: "THIRD STRING";
  }
  75% {
    content: "FOURTH STRING";
  }
  100% {
    content: "FIRST STRING";
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="font-weight-dark mb-1"><span></span></h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not flag or comment with my current reputation, but this was answered here before, please flag it as duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078500/2498992

Comment: Thanks - I looked all over and that thread flew right under the radar. Answers my questions though.