# How to animate in Safari using CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, webkit

I have a problem. Safari doesn't want to work fine with my animation. It says nothing and shows nothing. In Google Chrome it works great, but doesn't in Safari. Here's my HTML-code:

```css
.funny_text:before {
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0%,
  34% {
    content: '123';
  }
  35%,
  67% {
    content: '456';
  }
  68%,
  100% {
    content: '789';
  }
}
@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  34% {
    content: '123';
  }
  35%,
  67% {
    content: '456';
  }
  68%,
  100% {
    content: '789';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="funny_text">
        </span> .Сайт
</p>
```

I need your help!

Comment: What version of Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@keyframes animate {}`, for compatiblity with Safari 4.0-8.0 you need to use `@-webkit-keyframes example {}` together with the `@keyframes animate {}`

Comment: In fact, I'm using @-webkit-feyframes and also @keyframes, but it's still not working, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@webkit-keyframes animate {}` as well.

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
0%,34%{
    content: '123';
}
35%,67%{
    content: '456';
}
68%,100%{
    content: '789';
}
```

}

Comment: In fact, I'm using @-webkit-keyframes, but it's still not working, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: can you try to use -webkit-animation: animate in your css instead of " animation-name". So called it: animation: animate and -webkit-animation: animate. And maybe just to be sure, give your animation a different name instead of animate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even that way it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083297/6691092 
 https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/#article-header-id-2